# Cout inside while?

Tags: c++

```
int main() {

    int count = 0;
    string prev = " "; 
    string current;
    while (cin>>current)

    {
        ++count;
        if (prev == current)
        {
            cout << "count of repeated: " << count << "\n" << "repeated words: " + current + "\n";
            
        }
    prev = current;        
    }
     

}
```

this works but when i use:

```
 if (prev == current)
    {
        cout << "repeated words: " + current + "\n";
        cout << "count of repeated words: " + count; 
    }
```

the cout for count is removing a character for each count.
why is that?
Also why i cant put "\n" after count?

Thanks

output:

ha
ho
ha
ha
repeated words: ha
t of repeated words:
hi
ho
ho
repeated words: ho
f repeated words:

Comment: What do you mean by 'the cout for count is removing a character for each count"? What character is removed? Please show some example output.

Comment: Why are you using `+` when you want `<<`?

Comment: Better spend a few more time to explain what you actually want.

Comment: If `"foo"` is a pointer to the string "foo", what do you think `"foo"+1` is?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice it was removing characters from the string "count of repeated words: ".  example:  ha
ho
ha
ha
repeated words: ha   
t of repeated words: 
hi
ho
ho
repeated words: ho
f repeated words:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You clearly think that this code

```
cout << "count of repeated words: " + count;
```

is going to append `count` to the rest of the output, but it doesn't. Look up *pointer arithmetic* if you want to know what it really does, 'removing a character for each count' is a reasonable summary though.

The way to get what you want is this

```
cout << "count of repeated words: " << count << "\n";
```

And similarly your first line is better written as this

```
cout << "repeated words: " << current << "\n";
```

Although in that case because `current` is a `string`, `+` really does append two strings. But still the `<<` version is more efficient because it outputs the data without constructing any new strings.